# No email or email_verified claim in Google ID token

Tags: google-oauth, google-openidconnect

Our app allows users to sign in with Google account and uses Google API client library for ID token validation.

According to the [Google doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#an-id-tokens-payload), `email` claim is supposed to be contained in the ID token payload when the scope includes the `email` scope value.

However, I noticed in some cases, `email` or `email_verified`claim is missing from the ID token payload though the `email` scope value is included.

Why is this happening? I suppose a Google account always has a verified email address on the profile.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the team about this very question several years ago.   They do not guarantee that the claims will come with every call.

The work around is

If you make a request to the userinfoendpoint

```
GET /oauth2/v2/userinfo HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer [accessToken]
```

Response

```
{
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhroCYJp2P9xeYeYk1npchBPK-zbtTxzNQo0WAHI20", 
  "verified_email": true, 
  "id": "11720047553267277534", 
  "email": "xxxxxxx@gmail.com"
}
```

Assuming you have requested the email scope email and verified_email will return every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
GET /oauth2/v2/userinfo HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer [accessToken]

{
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhroCYJp2P9xeYeYk1npchBPK-zbtTxzNQo0WAHI20", 
  "verified_email": true, 
  "id": "11720047553267277534", 
  "email": "xxxxxxx@gmail.com"
}
```